# Typescript React No overload matches this call Type: 'StoreData | undefined' is not assignable to type 'StoreData'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a react app that is compiling with errors while using the Reducer function.

the script where the error is:

```
import { StoreReducer } from "./reducer";
import { StoreData, StoreAction } from "./types";

export const dataStore: Store<StoreData, StoreAction> = createStore(StoreReducer);
```

I'm assuming the problem is in the reducer.ts script:

```
import { ACTIONS, StoreData, StoreAction } from "./types";
import { Order } from "./entities";
import { Reducer } from "react";

//fn Reducer<S,A> where S is type that represents shape of the ds, 
//A is the type thar represents the actions the ds supports
export const StoreReducer: Reducer<StoreData, StoreAction> 
  = (data: StoreData | undefined , action) => {

  data  = data || { products: [], order: new Order() }
  switch(action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.ADD_PRODUCTS:                             
      return {
        ...data,
        products: [...data.products, ...action.payload]
      };

    case ACTIONS.MODIFY_ORDER:
      data.order.addProduct(action.payload.product, action.payload.quantity);
      return {...data};
    
    case ACTIONS.RESERT_ORDER:
      return {
        ...data,
        order: new Order()
      }
    default:
      return data;
  }
}
```

The error I get:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call
...
 Overload 1 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<StoreData, StoreAction>, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<Store<StoreData, StoreAction>, unknown> | undefined): Store<...>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'React.Reducer<import("reactapp/src/data/types").StoreData, import("reactapp/src/data/types").StoreAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type
'import("reactapp/node_modules/redux/index").Reducer<import("reactapp/src/data/types").StoreData, import("reactapp/src/data/types").StoreAction>'. 
Types of parameters 'prevState' and 'state' are incompatible.
Type 'StoreData | undefined' is not assignable to type 'StoreData'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'StoreData'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<StoreData, StoreAction>, preloadedState?: { products: { id: number; name: string; description: string; category: string; price: number; }[]; order: { ...; }; } | undefined, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<...> | undefined): Store<...>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'React.Reducer<import("reactapp/src/data/types").StoreData, import("reactapp/src/data/types").StoreAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("reactapp/node_modules/redux/index").Reducer<import("reactapp/src/data/types").StoreData, import("reactapp/src/data/types").StoreAction>'.
    5 |
    6 | //use Redux createStore method to create ds object
  > 7 | export const dataStore: Store<StoreData, StoreAction> = createStore(StoreReducer);
```

I've tried removing the "undefined" in `export const StoreReducer: Reducer<StoreData, StoreAction>  = (data: StoreData | undefined , action)` because I thought it didn't like that it could be undefined but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your problem at hand by using it as a default value:

```
export const StoreReducer: Reducer<StoreData, StoreAction> 
  = (data: StoreData = { products: [], order: new Order() }, action) => {
```

That said, you probably should not be writing code like this.
This is an extremely outdated style of Redux. We are officially recommending to use the official Redux Toolkit since 2019 - even in legacy projects. You will end up writing 1/4 of the code and almost no TypeScript types.

Please give a read to [Why Redux Toolkit is how to use Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today).

If you are just learning Redux and need a good tutorial, please go with the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

Comment: What parts of this code are outdated? I'm copying directly from a book "Essential Typescript 4", I was hoping it was still recent enough.

Comment: @Mitch : all of it :)  Today, we don't want people writing reducers "by hand". Instead, you should use Redux Toolkit's `createSlice` API, like this: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-slice-state-and-action-types

Comment: @Mitch If this is suppoed to be `redux` code (like you tagged it), there is literally not a single line of code in there that is not outdated. Modern Redux has no `ACTION_TYPES`, no `switch..case` reducers, no immutable reducer logic with `...`spreads, you don't create a `StoreAction` union type.
If you just want to write reducers for React's `useReducer` hook, they never evolved forward from that style - but even then you can use Redux Toolkit's `createSlice` reducers with `useReducer`.

Comment: @phry it still has the same error...but if this is as outdated way to use redux/react I think I should go and learn the "correct" way anyway